# How can i fetch data of checked checkbox in repeater when click on button?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have code of repeater like this .Now when i click on button i want `job_id`  of selected checkbox.

```
 `<asp:Repeater ID="rptJob" runat="server" >

          <ItemTemplate>

          <td valign="middle" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px">

           <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="604">
                     <tr>
                     <td width="3%" valign="top">  
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CssClass="search-link"/>
                     </td>
                     <td valign="middle" align="left">
                       <a href="display_job.aspx?jobId=`<%# Eval("job_id")`%>&empId= "` # Eval("emp_id") %>"`  target="_blank">        
                       <asp:Label ID="title"  runat="server"> 
                       <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "job_title")%>    </asp:Label>                                                                   
</a>                            </td>
</asp:Repeater>`
```

In code behind what i have to write on button click event?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to solve this issue.  Assuming the button click causes a postback I'd choose one of the two:

- Switch to the ListView control (instead of the Repeater) and utilize this DataKeyNames property.  You'll need to add a handler for the CheckBox's CheckChanged event as well.  The accepted answer here should be of help in implementing the handler: http://forums.asp.net/t/1581511.aspx/1
- Subclass the CheckBox control and add a property to store the job ID.  Add a handler for the CheckChanged event (in the handler, cast the sender argument to your newly subclassed checkbox).  In the aspx/ascx page, bind the job_id to the newly added property.

  ```
  [ToolboxData(@"<{0}:JobCheckBox runat=""server""></{0}:JobCheckBox>")]
  public class JobCheckBox : CheckBox
  {

      [Category("Data")]
      [DefaultValue(0)]
      [Description("The Job ID associated with this checkbox.")]
      //  Assuming the job ID is an int
      public int JobId
      {
          get { return (ViewState["JobId"] is int) ? (int)ViewState["JobId"] : 0; }
          set { ViewState["JobId"] = value; }
      }
  }
  ```